# How to display specific number of lines of .log file in terminal?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am using

```
tail -n 5/access.log
```

to display last 5 lines but it shows 
"Invalid number of lines" but there are 10 lines in this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right syntax is:    `tail -n 5 access.log`

Or just `tail -5 sccess.log`